# nvd3 lineplusbar chart different data in one graph

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I have a following graph:
[image]

Graph contains of dividends from company Johnson & Johnson. I needed to add future 10 year prediction for dividends = add new color to distinguish between them. So I was googling around and found function to change color:

```
d3.selectAll("rect.nv-bar").style("fill", function(d){
                if (d.x < {{ current_year_timestamp|date:"U000" }}) {
                    return "#1f77b4";
                } else if (d.x == {{ current_year_timestamp|date:"U000" }}) {
                    return "#2ca02c";
                } else {
                    return "#7f7f7f";
                }
            });
```

but it lacks two things. First is that there is no legend for green and gray bars. Second thing is that if I reset graph by clicking on Dividends (left axis) in legend, all bars are blue(function is not used anymore).
Any idea how can I fix this? I was thinking about adding data for future (10 years) dividends somehow separate from dividend history and nvd3 would recognize it as different data and it would have it's own "reset" button in legend. Can it be done with little nvd3 code changes?
This is my full js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        nv.addGraph(function() {
            var testdata = exampleData(),
                    chart = nv.models.linePlusBarChart()
                            .margin({top: 30, right: 70, bottom: 50, left: 70})
                            .x(function(d, i) { return i })
                            .color(d3.scale.category10().range())
                            .tooltipContent(function(key, x, y, e, graph) {
                                if (x < new Date().getFullYear()) {
                                    return '<h3>Dividend history</h3><p>' +  y + ' for ' + x + '</p>'
                                } else if (x == new Date().getFullYear()) {
                                    return '<h3>This year\'s dividends</h3><p>' +  y + ' for ' + x + '</p>'
                                } else {
                                    return '<h3>Future dgr10 dividends</h3><p>' +  y + ' for ' + x + '</p>'
                                }
                            })
            chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
                var dx = testdata[0].values[d] && testdata[0].values[d].x || 0;
                return d3.time.format('%Y')(new Date(dx))
            });

            chart.y1Axis
                    .tickFormat(d3.format(',05f'));

            chart.y2Axis
                    .tickFormat(function(d) { return '$' + d3.format(',05f')(d) });

            chart.bars.forceY([0]);

            chart.lines.forceY([0]);

            d3.select('#chart svg')
                    .datum(exampleData())
                    .transition().duration(500).call(chart);
            first_timestamp = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 1, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0);
            d3.selectAll("rect.nv-bar").style("fill", function(d){
                if (d.x < {{ current_year_timestamp|date:"U000" }}) {
                    return "#1f77b4";
                } else if (d.x == {{ current_year_timestamp|date:"U000" }}) {
                    return "#2ca02c";
                } else {
                    return "#7f7f7f";
                }
            });
            nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

            return chart;
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function exampleData() {
            return [
                {
                    "key" : "Dividends" ,
                    "bar": true,
                    "values" : [
                        {% for dividend in dividend_list %}
                            [ {{ dividend.date|date:"U000" }} , {{ dividend.amount|floatformat:"-3" }} ] {% if not forloop.last  %}, {% endif %}
                        {% empty %}
                            []
                        {% endfor %}
                    ]
                } ,

                {
                    "key" : "Dividends together" ,
                    "values" : [
                        {% with totalDividend=0.0 %}
                            {% for dividend in dividend_list %}
                                [ {{ dividend.date|date:"U000" }} , {% set_by 'totalDividend' totalDividend|add_float:dividend.amount as totalDividend %}{{ totalDividend|floatformat:"-3" }} ]
                                {% if not forloop.last  %}, {% endif %}
                            {% empty %}
                                []
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endwith %}
                    ]
                }
            ].map(function(series) {
                        series.values = series.values.map(function(d) { return {x: d[0], y: d[1] } });
                        return series;
                    });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: You have to implement this functionality yourself, NVD3 doesn't support it. The changes you would have to make are not minor.